# How exactly does the this keyword work in JS?

Tags: javascript

I am fairly new to JS, although I have decent experience in other languages.
From my understanding, in JS, when in a method, `this` refers to it's owner object.

```
var superman = {
    name : 'Superman',
    sayHi : function(){ 
        alert("Hello, I'm "+this.name) 
        }
    };
```

When I write,

```
var print = superman.sayHi()

print()
```

It alerts, `Hello, I'm Superman` as expected.

However, if I write,

```
var print = superman.sayHi

print()
```

It alerts, `Hello, I'm undefined`

Why does this happen? The `this` in superman should refer to superman object, why is `var print = superman.sayHi()` and `var print = superman.sayHi` producing different outputs?

Comment: That's a good question! But i think it does not suit this platform since it has already been answered several times here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/

Comment: `this` shall always look in the current scope, in your example `sayHi` is a function, so when you call `this.name` there is no `name` property within the `sayHi` function scope, so you get undefined.  You would need to bind the scope to that function or don't create a new function scope, see: https://repl.it/repls/SeparateFrillyApplicationframework#index.js

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Answer (score 0):

Actually `this` is passed as a default argument to all functions only

**Note: Only function calls**

What is happening in your code is that

when you execute `var print = superman.sayHi()` you call a function sayHi and `this` is passed by default

And in this case `var print = superman.sayHi` no value of `this` is passed.

So it prints `undefined` as the value of this.name.

You can either do this

```
var superman = {
name : 'Superman',
sayHi : "Hello, I'm "+name
};

//and then print sayHi

alert(superman.sayHi);
```